# Algebraic reductions of signed integer expressions in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, integer

I wanted to see if GCC would reduce `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` with signed and unsigned integers so I created two tests

```
//test1.c
unsigned fooau(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) { return a - (b - c); }
signed   fooas(signed   a, signed   b, signed   c) { return a - (b - c); }
signed   fooms(signed   a) { return a*a*a*a*a*a; }
unsigned foomu(unsigned a) { return a*a*a*a*a*a; }  

//test2.c
unsigned fooau(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) { return (a + c) - b; }
signed   fooas(signed   a, signed   b, signed   c) { return (a + c) - b; }
signed   fooms(signed   a) { return (a*a*a)*(a*a*a); }
unsigned foomu(unsigned a) { return (a*a*a)*(a*a*a); }
```

I compiled first with `gcc -O3 test1.c test2.c -S` and looked at the assembly.  For both tests `fooau` were identical however `fooas` was not.

As far as I understand unsigned arithmetic can be derived from [the following formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/what-are-the-properties-of-the-modulus)

```
(a%n + b%n)%n = (a+b)%n
```

which can be used to show that unsigned arithmetic is associative. But since [signed overflow is undefined behavior](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120)  this equality does not necessarily hold for signed addition (i.e. signed addition is not associative) which explains why GCC did not reduce `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` for signed integers. But we can tell GCC to use this formula using `-fwrapv`. Using this option `fooas` for both tests is identical.

But what about multiplication?  For both tests `fooms` and `foomu` were simplified to three multiplications (`a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)`). But multiplication can be written as repeated addition so using the formula above I think it can be shown that

```
((a%n)*(b%n))%n = (a*b)%n
```

which I think can also show that unsigned modular multiplication is associative as well.  But since GCC used only three multiplications for `foomu` this shows that GCC assumes signed integer multiplication is associative.

This seems like a contradiction to me. For addition signed arithmetic was not associative but for multiplication it is.

Two questions:

1. Is it true that addition is not associative with signed integers but multiplication is in C/C++?
2. If signed overflow is used for optimization isn't the fact that GCC not reducing the algebraic expression a failure to optimize? Wouldn't it better better for optimization to use `-fwrapv` (I understand that `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` is not much of a reduction but I'm worried about more complicated cases)? Does this mean for optimization sometimes using `-fwrapv` is more efficient and sometimes it's not?

Comment: What happens to `fooms` and `foomu` if you make the body `a*a*a*a*a` - ie. an **odd** number of multiplies? Do they still optimize the same? With an even number, sign is irrelevant as the result will always be positive.

Comment: @kdopen, it's the same: `fooms` and `foomu` produce the same code and use 3 multiplications for `a*a*a*a*a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, multiplication is not associative in signed integers. Consider `(0 * x) * x` vs. `0 * (x * x)` - the latter has potentially undefined behavior while the former is always defined.
2. The potential for undefined behavior only ever introduces *new* optimization opportunities, the classic example being optimizing `x + 1 > x` to `true` for signed `x`, an optimization that is not available for unsigned integers.

I don't think you can assume that gcc failing to change `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` represents a missed optimization opportunity; the two calculations compile to the same two instructions on x86-64 (`leal` and `subl`), just in a different order.

Indeed, the *implementation* is entitled to assume that arithmetic is associative, and use that for optimizations, since anything can happen on UB including modulo arithmetic or infinite-range arithmetic. However, *you* as the programmer are not entitled to assume associativity unless you can guarantee that no intermediate result overflows.

As another example, try `(a + a) - a` - gcc will optimize this to `a` for signed `a` as well as for unsigned.

Comment: Why the first has potentially UB? Because of large values?

Comment: @G.Samaras yes, `x * x` can overflow.

Comment: As to your second point GCC did not reduce `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` because overflow for signed is UB but when I used `-fwrapv` which means signed overflow is defined behavior it does reduce. Doesn't that mean GCC avoided an optimization opportunity due to UB?

Comment: @Zboson it's hard to see that rewrite as a reduction, let alone an optimization - it's accessing the same registers and using the same instructions, just in a different order. It might make a difference within a larger execution, but you haven't provided the compiler an opportunity to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 2):

Algebraic reduction of signed integer expressions can be performed provided it has the same result for any *defined* set of inputs. So if the expression

```
a * a * a * a * a * a
```

is defined -- that is, `a` is small enough that no signed overflow occurs during the computation -- then any regrouping of the multiplications will produce the same value, because no product of less than six `a`s can overflow.

The same would be true for `a + a + a + a + a + a`.

Things change if the variables multiplied (or added) are not all the same, or if the additions are intermingled with subtractions. In those cases, regrouping and rearranging the computation could lead to a signed overflow which did not occur in the canonical computation.

For example, take the expression

```
a - (b - c)
```

Algebraically, that's equivalent to

```
(a + c) - b
```

But the compiler can not do that rearrangement because it is possible that the intermediate value `a+c` will overflow with inputs which would not cause an overflow in the original. Suppose we had `a=INT_MAX-1; b=1; c=2;` then `a+c` results in an overflow, but `a - (b - c)` is computed as `a - (-1)`, which is `INT_MAX`, without overflow.

If the compiler can assume that signed overflow does not trap but instead is computed modulo `INT_MAX+1`, then these rearrangements are possible. The `-fwrapv` options allows gcc to make that assumption.

Comment: But `a*a*a*a*a*a` certainly can overflow and `fooms` has to assume any `a` and GCC reduces this even without `-fwrapv`.

Comment: @Zboson: GCC is allowed to assume that `a*a*a*a*a*a` will not overflow, because if it overflowed that would result in undefined behaviour. (Undefined behaviour cancels all obligations, so to speak.) So GCC only needs to ensure consistency in the case that no overflow would occur with the canonical computation `((((((a*a)*a)*a)*a)*a)*a)`. If no overflow occurs in that case, no overflow occurs in the computation `(((a*a)*a)*((a*a)*a))`, so the substitution is valid.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. Since GCC can assume overflow does not happen it can use infinite-range arithmetic if it wants which is associative. I'm still learning C.

Comment: @Zboson: That's the most important thing about undefined behaviour; images of flying lizards are colourful but not usually relevant. The compiler is always allowed to assume that a program as written does not produce undefined behaviour, and it can (and does) optimize according to that assumption.

Comment: It's still strange to me then that it does not convert `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` for signed when it does for unsigned. If it assumes `a - (b - c)` for signed can use infinite-range arithmetic then it can convert  `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b`.

Comment: @Zboson: It can't convert `a-(b-c)` to `(a+c)-b` because `a+c` might overflow in a situation in which the original expression was well-defined. Edited the answer with that example.

Comment: I understand your point that `(a+c)-b` could overflew in a situation where `a-(b+c)` did not. But `a-(b+c)` can overflow as well. Since signed overflow is UB isn't GCC free to assume no overflow occurs and assume that `a-(b+c)` is the same as `(a+c)-b`?

Comment: @zboson: the compiler can assume that the program as written wont overflow. That is, that the programmer has computed a, b and c in a way which guarantees that the expressiin using those variables won't cause UB. It can't assume that some other expression not in the program won't cause UB.

Comment: @rice, okay I think I finally get it now. I was hung up because e.g. `((((a*a)*a)*a)*a)*a` could potentially have UB at a different sub-expression than `(a*a*a)*(a*a*a)` but the point is that either way the UB would be for the same value of `a`. Whereas with `a - (b - c)` to `(a + c) - b` the UB could be at different e.g. values of `a`.